# How to remove first 16 characters of all file names in a directory?

Tags: rename, file-rename

I have a directory with many files with really long, repetitive names and I would like to remove the first 16 characters from each file name.

So I would like to rename files like this:

```
0123456789012345file1.fits
0123456789012345file2.fits
```

to this:

```
file1.fits
file2.fits
```

I would like to be able to do this from the command line in the terminal.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash, you can run

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:16}"; done
```

to rename all files stripping off the first 16 characters of the name.

You can change the `*` to a more restrictive pattern such as `*.fits` if you don't want to rename all files in the current directory. The quotes around the parameters to `mv` are necessary if any filenames contain whitespace.

bash's `${var:pos:len}` syntax also supports more advanced usage than the above. You can take only the first five characters with `${f::5}`, or the first five characters after removing the first 16 characters with `${f:16:5}`. Many other variable substitution expressions are available in bash; see a reference such as [TLDP's Bash Parameter Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more information.